# Ways of implementing "Change Requests" behaviour in SPD 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, designer-workflow, tasks

I am implementing SPD 2013 workflow and have to add possibility to change requests in every task. In SPD2010 WFs we could set the Change Requests button and it created all the behaviour behind the scenes.

[image]

But I don't know how to create a new task (to request changes) from a current task. In addition to it we should recreate current task after request changes is complete. 
How can we implement it in SPD 2013 WFs?

**I can see two ways:**

1. Not create new task, but change assignee and other fields of the current task and show different views of the current task depending on it current goal (current or request changes).
2. As we can create state-machine WFs in SPD2013, I could add new task outcome (RequestChanges for instance) and if current task completes with this Outcome we could go on step Request Changes and return to the previous step after it.

**These are possible workarounds, but maybe there is a better solution? Does anybody have any ideas?**